# handler socket on tokudb engine

Tags: mysql, tokudb, handler-socket

I am trying to setup handler socket to work with tokudb engine. Database I am running is percona server and i have got tokudb enabled and the tables all have tokudb engine.

I was wondering if anyone knows handler socket is compatible with tokudb aswell.

Any advise on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What benefit are you expecting from Handler Socket?

Comment: using handler socket interface we can increase our insert/update performance for certain tables, which is several times more than what we can get from innodb or tokudb

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB [documentation page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/handlersocket/) for HandlerSocket says:

```
HandlerSocket gives you direct access to InnoDB/XtraDB and SPIDER.
```

It doesn't mention TokuDB (despite it being distributed with MariaDB), so I would exclude that this engine is supported.